# Use Yii2 REST API can not get a query parameters in QueryParamAuth.php

Tags: yii2

When I use the QueryParamAuth function to connect to my API I get this error:

```
“data”: {
“name”: “Unauthorized”,
“message”: “Your request was made with invalid credentials.”,
“code”: 0,
“status”: 401,
“type”: “yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException”
}
```

This is my behaviors:

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => QueryParamAuth::class,
        'tokenParam' => 'access-token',
    ];
```

So I'm trying to connect to my API using a token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to QueryParamAuth.php in the Yii2 project to request the `acces-token` directly without going through the `tokenParam` declaration.

```
public function authenticate($user, $request, $response)
{
    $accessToken = $request->get('acces-token');
    if (is_string($accessToken)) {
        $identity = $user->loginByAccessToken($accessToken, get_class($this));
        if ($identity !== null) {
            return $identity;
        }
    }
    if ($accessToken !== null) {
        $this->handleFailure($response);
    }

    return null;
}
```